# How do I set different line-heights in the same paragraph or header?

Tags: html, css

I've read that headers shouldn't be used as subtexts to other headers for HTML5 in order to have a nice outline.
for example:

```
<h1>Frustration</h1><br />
<h2>The life of developers</h2>
```

Rather, it could be written like this instead:

```
<h1>Frustration
    <br />
    <span style="font-size: 0.67em">The life of developers</span>
</h1>
```

The problem is that I have no control on the line-height of the subtext. It takes on the line-height of the H1 and that always seem a little too far.

I realize could do something like:

h1+.subtitle

to target the same thing, but I'd just like to know whether there is any way for the second option above to let me manipulate a paragraph with two different line-heights.

EDIT:
I'm using the latest version of Firefox.

As I continue to look for a solution, I'm beginning to wonder if this is a silly question to be asking, seeing as the browser has no reason to think the user would want separate line-heights within the same tag--especially when there are alternatives like using block elements with a negative margin-top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<h1>
  <span class="mainText">Frustration</span> 
  <span class="subText">The life of developers</span>
</h1>


h1 .mainText {
 display: block; /* this prevent the need for the <br/> */
 /* additional style for the main header text */
}
h1 .subText {
  /* styling for the subtext */
}
```

You could also do this (which is easier I guess):

```
<h1>text
    <div>subtext</div>
</h1>


h1 div {
  font-size: 0.67em
}
```

The subtext will have a lower line height. See this jsfiddle for the latter one: http://jsfiddle.net/wLD35/

Comment: I like the idea of using a block element within the h1 tag. However, the div within the H1 is still subject to the H1's line-height.  I suppose I can just do a negative margin-top to offset the line-height..

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. When I take a look at this fiddle the lines if the div really have a different line-height than the first line: http://jsfiddle.net/wLD35/2/

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Sorry I took so long to reply. Got caught up with work.

Your response was great, but it doesn't actually work to my described setup of codes. However, the method you're offering (as well as suggestions by others) are in fact better than the way I was trying to do it.

I guess I was so stuck on thinking about how to do in the way I had set up, I didn't really think of why I was doing it to begin with. Thanks all for your time and help.